# How to disable "middle click on URL bar paste last websites URL" Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, xorg, copy-paste

When I open a site without highlighting the URL and then open a new empty tab Firefox copy's the previous site's URL to the Xorg selection register such that middle click pastes the your last tabs URL
How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the setting `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll:true` under about:config. If you disable this setting firefox will not mess with the xorg selection register.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `about:config` from address bar.
2. Search `middlemouse.paste`.
3. Change value into `false`.